Yii2 form submitting twice when using imageuploadify
I have a Yii2 form that uses imageuploadify to load images. The form is being submitted twice, resulting in multiple entries on the create action.
My controller function is checking for Ajax but the submission is not being caught here.
I searched the upload code and found indeed the form is being submitted. Seems the stopPropagation() is not stopping the Yii form submission. I don't really want to edit the JS code.
How can I prevent the double submit.
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'accommodation-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'options' => ['class' => 'form-vertical'],
                ]);
   ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'accommodation_images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*', 'class' => 'form-control '])->label(false); ?>

<?php
$script = <<<JS

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#accommodationform-accommodation_images').imageuploadify();
        });

JS;
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_READY, 'fancy-file-upload-script');
?>

My controller function is checking for Ajax but the submission is not being caught here,
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    if ($formModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        return ActiveForm::validate($formModel);
    }
}

I searched the upload code and found indeed the form is being submitted.
 // When submitting the form.
      $(self).closest("form").on("submit", function(event) {
        // Stop the original submit.
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault(event);
        // Retrieve all form inputs.
        const inputs = this.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select, button");
        // Create a form.
        const formData = new FormData();

        // Add all data to the form (selected options, checked inputs, etc...).
        for (let index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
          if (inputs[index].tagName === "SELECT" && inputs[index].hasAttribute("multiple")) {
            const options = inputs[index].options;
            for (let i = 0; options.length > i; ++i) {
              if (options[i].selected) {
                formData.append(inputs[index].getAttribute("name"), options[i].value);
              }
            }
          }
          else if (!inputs[index].getAttribute("type") || ((inputs[index].getAttribute("type").toLowerCase()) !== "checkbox" && (inputs[index].getAttribute("type").toLowerCase()) !== "radio") || inputs[index].checked) {
            formData.append(inputs[index].name, inputs[index].value);
          }
          else if ($(inputs[index]).getAttribute("type") != "file") {
            formData.append(inputs[index].name, inputs[index].value);  
          }
        }

        // Add all files get from the dialog box or drag'n drop,
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles.length; i++) {
          formData.append(self.name, totalFiles[i].file);
        }

        // Create an request and post all data.
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // When the request has been successfully submitted, redirect to the
        // location of the form.
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            window.location.replace(xhr.responseURL);
          }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", $(this).attr("action"), true);
        xhr.send(formData);

        return false;
      });

References : https://github.com/wpic/imageuplodify/blob/master/imageuploadify.js

Disable enableAjaxValidation which causes twice submission for file uploads.
